# PowerShell: Unable to Import-CSV with line break

Tags: powershell, csv, import, delimiter

thing like this, i would like to import text file data into access. The data content example like this: (example.txt)

```
ID | Name | Message | User
----------------------------
1 | Joe | This is a text, error message | admin
2 | Mary | No error message, ID number: 9182734 | normal-user
3 | Terry | This is a long text, long message. Product ID : 1234,
Tag ID : fhdj123, Please restart | admin
```

I use -Delimiter "|" as a separator, and it works well for ID 1 and ID 2, but when comes to ID 3, it will just read until "...product ID :1234," then stop. After then, it start read new line from "Tag ID". As you guys can see the "|" is not close at end of ID 3. I wonder how to read string with line break. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your csv. Values that include linebreaks or the delimeter-character, needs to be quoted. You should also remove line 2(the `----------------`-line) before importing.

Ex.

```
ID | Name | Message | User
1 | Joe | This is a text, error message | admin
2 | Mary | No error message, ID number: 9182734 | normal-user
3 | Terry | "This is a long text, long message. Product ID : 1234,
Tag ID : fhdj123, Please restart" | admin
```

Import:

```
PS > import-csv -Delimiter "|" .\Desktop\test.csv 

ID  Name   Message                                                    User       
--- -----  --------                                                   ----       
1   Joe    This is a text, error message                              admin      
2   Mary   No error message, ID number: 9182734                       normal-user
3   Terry  This is a long text, long message. Product ID : 1234,...   admin
```

You could also replace the linebreaks in the file before importing, but I'm guessing that you need the values as-is.

Comment: Yes, this solve my problem easily, just add a double quotation between message line break. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to parse your import file and replace *coma followed by line break sequence* with just a coma. This could be  `` ,`n `` or `` ,`r `` depending on the format of your file.
This should do the trick:

```
gc example.txt | Out-String | % { 
    $_.replace(",`r",",").replace(",`n",",") } | Set-Content example.txt
```

and then run your `import-csv`

```
PS D:\>Import-Csv example.txt -Delimiter "|"
```

which will result in correct assignment of columns:

```
ID                      Name                    Message                User
---                     -----                   --------               ----
--------------------...
1                       Joe                     This is a text, err... admin
2                       Mary                    No error message, I... normal-user
3                       Terry                   This is a long text... admin
```

You could also remove the mulitple hyphens to make the file easier to read.